# Intersecting large vector of time intervals with reference time intervals in R

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe` with a column of `lubridate` time intervals (reflecting the state of a machine that was operating at this time). The intervals span from minutes to hours and days and can occur at any time of the day. I now want to aggregate how much time the compartment was operating for a given time interval, e.g. operating time per day, per hour, etc.

The data recieved from the machine is processed and, afterwards, looks somewhat like the following dummy data:

```
# Dummy interval data
interval_data <- c(interval(ymd_hm("2024-02-10 22:00"), ymd_hm("2024-02-11 08:00")),
               interval(ymd_hm("2024-02-12 15:30"), ymd_hm("2024-02-13 07:45")),
               interval(ymd_hm("2024-02-14 21:00"), ymd_hm("2024-02-16 06:30")))
```

I now want to intersect this data with a predefined time interval (e.g. hours or days) and recieve the amount of minutes the machine was operating in each given interval. The output that I expect to recieve looks like the following, whereby here the duration is in minutes:

```
days       duration
2024-02-10      120
2024-02-11      480
2024-02-12      510
2024-02-13      465
2024-02-14      180
2024-02-15     1440
2024-02-16      390
```

I have tried to generate the wanted reference time interval and then loop over every possibility between reference and dummy data; however, the output is convoluted and I am having troubles to summarize the data.

Comment: rule #1: notice you almost never loop over anything in R; rule #2: if you find yourself looping in R, see rule #1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

interval_data <- c(interval(ymd_hm("2024-02-10 22:00"), ymd_hm("2024-02-11 08:00")),
                   interval(ymd_hm("2024-02-12 15:30"), ymd_hm("2024-02-13 07:45")),
                   interval(ymd_hm("2024-02-14 21:00"), ymd_hm("2024-02-16 06:30")))

tibble(
  days = seq(date(min(int_start(interval_data))),
             date(max(int_end(interval_data))),
             by = "day")
) %>% 
  mutate(duration = map_dbl(days, ~ sum(as.duration(intersect(interval(.x, .x %m+% days(1)), interval_data)), na.rm = TRUE)) / 60)



# A tibble: 7 x 2
  days       duration
  <date>        <dbl>
1 2024-02-10     120.
2 2024-02-11     480 
3 2024-02-12     510.
4 2024-02-13     465 
5 2024-02-14     180.
6 2024-02-15    1440.
7 2024-02-16     390
```

Comment: That's a very elegant answer! Thank you very much for your help. I've edited out the `map_dfr()` at the end as it's probably a lost snippet and leads to an error :-)

Answer (score 1):

just intersect the timespan you are seeking with your data, then summarise

```
check <- as.interval(ymd_hm("2023-01-01 00:00"), ymd_hm("2024-02-12 16:00"))

sum(intersect(interval_data, check), na.rm=TRUE)
```

UPD:

```
fun <- function(check.i) {
  return(sum(interval_data[!is.na(intersect(interval_data, check.i))], na.rm=TRUE))
}
as.duration(unlist(lapply(check, fun)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code return the total overlap between the defined start and end time of check. However I am looking for a solution when `check` would be multiple intervals with a defined length, e.g. days such as the following: `check <- interval(seq(as.POSIXct("2024-02-10"), as.POSIXct("2024-02-16"), by = "1 days"),                   seq(as.POSIXct("2024-02-11"), as.POSIXct("2024-02-17"), by = "1 days"))`

Comment: @Octopus notice the check you provided consists of two overlapping intervals (meaning they are redundant); is that intentional?

Comment: You are right, it is actually unintentional! The intervals should just include one day by itself, e.g. from `2024-02-15 00:00:00` to `2024-02-15 23:59:59`

Comment: @Octopus the solution you are seeking obviously involves groupingBy your data.frame, which should be a custom function involving the intersect() method suggested above, then aggregating the total duration; i am working on it using dplyr package

Comment: @Octopus i made an update to the answer; may seem dirty, but it seems it is doing what is requested